# Using Laravel 4 Facebook Login compare profile link when login

Tags: php, facebook, laravel, laravel-4

I'm wondering if anyone can help me, I am building a `Laravel-4` application that uses the `Facebook API`. Currently I've managed to gain a connection to facebook and can login to the application.

However I want to control where the users go based on if there facebook profile link exists in the `database`. Currently I've got a form that takes the `url` of their profile and inserts it into the DB.

This is my facebook profile link:

```
https://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=100006760337073
```

However when I make a request to facebook I get this response:

```
array(11) {
        ["id"]=> string(16) "1536122286623101" 
        ["email"]=> string(16) "jack@gmail.com" 
        ["first_name"]=> string(4) "Jack" 
        ["gender"]=> string(4) "male" 
        ["last_name"]=> string(8) "Coldrick" 
        ["link"]=> string(61) "https://www.facebook.com/app_scoped_user_id/1536122286623101/" ["locale"]=> string(5) "en_US"
        ["name"]=> string(13) "Jack Coldrick" 
        ["timezone"]=> int(1) 
        ["updated_time"]=> string(24) "2014-09-05T16:35:17+0000" 
        ["verified"]=> bool(true) 
}
```

The `['link']` does not match the `profile link` in the url bar so my logic won't work because I am comparing these two. I'm wondering what the best way would be to store the users profile in the `db` and when they login check to see if they exist in the `db`.

Any help is much appreciated.

This is my `controller`

```
public function handleAddFacebook(){
        //Make an entry into the winners table of the DB
        $facebookWinner = new FacebookWinner();
        $facebookWinner->profile_link = Input::get('link');
        $facebookWinner->origin = Input::get('origin');
        $facebookWinner->destination = Input::get('destination');
        $facebookWinner->win_date = date('Y-m-d');
        $facebookWinner->save();
        return View::make('admin.dashboard');           
    }
```

Is there any way I could use the `Input::get('link')` to request the users id from facebook?

Comment: Do you need to compare on profile URL? Surely you could store the `id` field which is unique and never changes. The profile URL won't always return the same value, `/1536122286623101`, `profile.php?id=1536122286623101` and `/username` all go to the same page.

Comment: I thought about that but you see the way I intend on it working is the user provides the `link` via the admin and then using this link I would then have to somehow get the id? I guess I'm not sure how to do that because in some cases the profile url has a username and not an id

Comment: If you know their profile link to start with and are manually entering it into the database, the profile link contains either their username or ID. If the user who logs in has a username, you get an additional field in the response from FB containing the username. That means you have their username if present, and definitely their ID. If the ID or username matches one in your database, it's that person.